# Java Regex to remove start/end single quotes but leave inside quotes

Tags: java, regex, csv, replace

I have data from a CSV file that is enclosed in single quotes, like:

```
'Company name'
'Price: $43.50'
'New York, New York'
```

I want to be able to replace the single quotes at the start/end of the value but leave quotes in the data, like:

```
'Joe's Diner'  should become Joe's Diner
```

I can do

```
updateString = theString.replace("^'", "").replace("'$", "");
```

but I wanted to know if I could combine it to only do one replace.

Comment: You want to allow unbalanced quotes *and* use quotes to escape commas within a cell?  It is not possible to do both at once.

Comment: Yes, you can combine them quite easily.  Have another look at @Josiah's answer, now that he's using the correct method.

Answer (score 17):

You could use the **or** operator.

```
updateString = theString.replaceAll("(^')|('$)","");
```

See if that works for you :)

Comment: I had to change it to replaceAll, but then it worked.  If you update your answer, I'll accept it

Comment: I need opposite of this. I want to convert this 
//*[@text='some'Text']  
to //*[@text='some\'Text']

Answer (score 1):

```
updateString = theString.replaceFirst("^'(.*)'$", "$1");
```

Note that the form you have no won't work because [`replace`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) uses literal strings, not regexes.

This works by using a capturing group `(.*)`, which is referred to with `$1` in the replacement text.  You could also do something like:

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("^'(.*)'$"); // could be stored in a static final field.
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(theString);
boolean matches = matcher.matches();
updateString = matcher.group(1);
```

Of course, if you're certain there's a single quote at the beginning and end, the simplest solution is:

```
updateString = theString.substring(1, theString.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove double quotes around digits/numbers.

```
jsonString.replaceAll("\"(\\d+)\"","$1");
```

above will not work if negative numbers are present.

for negative numbers, the regex will be a little complex like below. But I haven't tried it.

```
"([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)"
```