# Remove only the surrounding single quotes?

Tags: javascript

So given the string: `'"Something's got to go"'` What's the proper way to remove only the surrounding single quotes? So the end result should be: `"Something's got to go"` notice the lack of surrounding single quotes.

I have attempted: `replace(/^'|'$/g, '"')` but alas this does not do the trick for me.

**Expected Result**:

The following: `'"Something's got to go"'`

Should become: `"Something's got to go"`

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315053/java-regex-to-remove-start-end-single-quotes-but-leave-inside-quotes) help? It's for Java but the regex is the same

Comment: I am really sorry but why do you need regex for this? Just check if they are and remove them c.substring(1, c.length-1); 
may be I missed smth?

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression you provided should work, see the example below:

```js
console.log(
 `'"Something's got to go"'`.replace(/^'|'$/g, '')
)
```