# How to remove quotes from front and end of the string Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala, apache-spark, trim

I have a dataframe where some strings contains "" in front and end of the string.

Eg:

```
+-------------------------------+
|data                           |
+-------------------------------+
|"john belushi"                 |
|"john mnunjnj"                 |
|"nmnj tyhng"                   |
|"John b-e_lushi"               |
|"john belushi's book"          |
```

Expected output:

```
+-------------------------------+
|data                           |
+-------------------------------+
|john belushi                   |
|john mnunjnj                   |
|nmnj tyhng                     |
|John b-e_lushi                 |
|john belushi's book            |
```

I am trying to remove only " double quotes from the string. Can some one tell me how can I remove this in Scala ?

Python provide ltrim and rtrim. Is there any thing equivalent to that in Scala ?

Comment: What's the problem with `"\"hello\"world".replaceAll("\"", "")` or `"\"hello\"world".filterNot(_ == '"')`? And what does it have to do with `trim` - it seems that you are deleting quotes everywhere, also in the middle of the string?

Comment: From your edit, it did not become clearer why the solutions from the first comment wouldn't work. Do you want to preserve the quotes in the middle of the string?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes. I would like to remove only the quotes that is in front and end of the string

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315053/java-regex-to-remove-start-end-single-quotes-but-leave-inside-quotes) answer your question? Just replace `'` by `"` in the regex: `"\"a \"b\" c\"".replaceAll("(^\")|(\"$)", "")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **expr, substring** and **length** functions and get the substring from `2` and `length() - 2`

```
val df_d = List("\"john belushi\"", "\"John b-e_lushi\"", "\"john belushi's book\"")
.toDF("data")
```

**`Input:`**

```
+---------------------+
|data                 |
+---------------------+
|"john belushi"       |
|"John b-e_lushi"     |
|"john belushi's book"|
+---------------------+
```

**`Using expr, substring and length functions:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

df_d.withColumn("data", expr("substring(data, 2, length(data) - 2)"))
    .show(false)
```

**`Output:`**

```
+-------------------+
|data               |
+-------------------+
|john belushi       |
|John b-e_lushi     |
|john belushi's book|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it

```
scala> val dataFrame = List("\"john belushi\"","\"john mnunjnj\"" , "\"nmnj tyhng\"" ,"\"John b-e_lushi\"", "\"john belushi's book\"").toDF("data")

scala> dataFrame.map { row => row.mkString.stripPrefix("\"").stripSuffix("\"")}.show

+-------------------+
|              value|
+-------------------+
|       john belushi|
|       john mnunjnj|
|         nmnj tyhng|
|     John b-e_lushi|
|john belushi's book|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to remove quotes from front and end of the string Scala?

*`myString.substring(1, myString.length()-1)`* will remove the double quotes.

```
  import spark.implicits._
val list = List("\"hi\"", "\"I am learning scala\"", "\"pls\"", "\"help\"").toDF()
list.show(false)
val finaldf = list.map {
  row => {
    val stringdoublequotestoberemoved = row.getAs[String]("value")

    stringdoublequotestoberemoved.substring(1, stringdoublequotestoberemoved.length() - 1)
  }
}
finaldf.show(false)
```

---

Result :

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|                "hi"|
|"I am learning sc...|
|               "pls"|
|              "help"|
+--------------------+

+-------------------+
|              value|
+-------------------+
|                 hi|
|I am learning scala|
|                pls|
|               help|
+-------------------+
```